# Playing xbox 360 at a friend's house

Tags: xbox-360

How does my son play online games on xbox 360 at a friend's house? Does he need to take his controller to get to his own live account or can he just use his friend's spare controller?

Answer (score 4):

You can sign in on any Xbox 360 just by entering your username and password on it, then downloading the profile. Accounts aren't linked to controllers, so he can use his friend's spare controller and still have his profile.

Answer (score 2):

Your son is most likely downloading his account onto his friend's Xbox 360. There's this highly used system called the [Cloud](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/games/cloud-save-games) that stores your data so you can play your games on another Xbox 360 wherever you had previously left off. Controllers have no storage data whatsoever, so bringing a controller won't do anything but add a player to his friend's Xbox console to play with him.